# Separating and formatting a multidimensional array by dates Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime, indexing

I am trying to write a code where it separates the data in months with the `month_changes`. The `Values` and `Val_dates` are corelated, `Val_dates` are supposed to be the matching dates for the `Values` indexes. So `[100,'2015-11-01 01:03:00'],[123, '2015-11-08 12:56:00'].....`. Each row in the multidimensional array is suppose to represent a single month so the first row `[100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72]` is for the November of 2015 and the sixth row `[100,106]` is for February of 2016 etc. I am trying to write a function where it iterates through the month rows as well as the number of valid indexes for that month. So for November of 2015 there are 4 dates that have the same month and year, `['2015-11-01 01:03:00', '2015-11-08 12:56:00', '2015-11-11 02:30:00', '2015-11-14 04:23:00']` so since the 4th index is the last on the first row it will output `139.05` which is the 4th index in `[100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72]`. For the rows that dont have any date matches it will just output 0.  How could I get the Expected Output?

```
import numpy as np 

#[23,10,3,12,5,6]
Values = np.array([[100,123,135.3,139.05,156.08,163.88,173.72],
                  [100,110,113,126.56,132.89,140.86],
                  [100,103,115.36,121.13,128.4],
                  [100,112,117.6,124.66],
                  [100,105,111.3],
                  [100,106]])

Val_dates= ['2015-11-01 01:03:00', '2015-11-08 12:56:00', '2015-11-11 02:30:00', '2015-11-14 04:23:00', '2016-02-11 02:00:00', '2016-02-15 15:00:00']

month_changes = ['2015-11-01 00:00:00', '2015-12-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
 '2016-02-01 00:00:00', '2016-03-01 00:00:00']

format_month = np.sort(month_changes)

def Monthly_Pnls(index, Values):
    # Digitize
    digit_month = np.digitize(index, format_month)
    Monthly_PnL = np.bincount(digit_month, weights=PnL)
    Monthly_PnL= np.around(Monthly_PnL[1:len(format_month)],1)
    print(Monthly_PnL)
    
    return Monthly_PnL

Monthly_Pnls(Val_dates, month_changes)
```

Expected Output:

```
[139.05,0,0,0,106,0]
```

Max Inputs:

```
Values = np.array([[123.         104.55       107.6865     105.53277    110.8094085
 117.45797301]
[85.       87.55     85.799    90.08895  95.494287]
[103.      100.94    105.987   112.34622]
[ 98.    102.9   109.074]
[105.  111.3]
[106.]])
```

Expected Output:

```
[123, 0.0, 0.0, 105.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: There is a problem: `len(Values)` -> 7 and `len(Val_dates)` -> 6

Comment: Corrected it thanks for letting me know

Comment: You're welcome. Do you accept an answer with Pandas (tomorrow)?

Comment: Yea pandas could work, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pandas to get expected result:

1. First convert to Pandas data structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': Val_dates, 'val': Values}).astype({'dt': 'datetime64'})
idx = pd.date_range(month_changes[0], month_changes[-1], freq='MS')
```

```
>>> df
                   dt                                                val
0 2015-11-01 01:03:00  [100, 123, 135.3, 139.05, 156.08, 163.88, 173.72]
1 2015-11-08 12:56:00            [100, 110, 113, 126.56, 132.89, 140.86]
2 2015-11-11 02:30:00                  [100, 103, 115.36, 121.13, 128.4]
3 2015-11-14 04:23:00                          [100, 112, 117.6, 124.66]
4 2016-02-11 02:00:00                                  [100, 105, 111.3]
5 2016-02-15 15:00:00                                         [100, 106]

>>> idx
DatetimeIndex(['2015-11-01', '2015-12-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01',
               '2016-03-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

2. Group by month, keep the first row of the group and get the right index:

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='dt'))['val'] \
      .apply(lambda x: x.head(1).squeeze()[len(x)-1] if len(x) else 0) \
      .reindex(idx, fill_value=0) \
      .tolist()

[139.05, 0.0, 0.0, 105.0, 0.0]
```

OR (without if/else)

```
>>> df.set_index('dt', drop=False).resample('MS')['val'] \
      .agg((len, 'first')).dropna(how='any') \
      .apply(lambda x: x['first'][x['len']-1], axis=1) \
      .reindex(idx, fill_value=0) \
      .tolist()

[139.05, 0.0, 0.0, 105.0, 0.0]
```

*The first method is 3x times faster than the second one*

Comment: hello is there a way to convert the code to get the `max` values for the code above by any chance? So if the `Values` were updated on the example above as the `Max Inputs` the values of the Expected Output would be `[123, 0.0, 0.0, 105.0, 0.0]`

Comment: Hey could you look at this issue it is just like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124802/separating-and-formatting-a-multidimensional-array-by-dates-python